# How do i resolve NullPointerException when calling methods?

Tags: android, class, android-intent, methods, nullpointerexception

I'm a noob to android and i am having an issue calling a method from another class.  The method works works fine when called from within its own class, but i get a nullpointerexception when i call it from another class.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is my code;

Calling method in class1 from class2:

```
BottlesActivity  inst = new BottlesActivity();
inst.call0();
```

Method in class 1:

```
public void call0() {
    try {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567890"/*+phonenumber0*/));
        startActivity(callIntent); //<--This line causes nullpointerexception
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
        Log.e("dialing-example", "Call failed", activityException);
    }
}
```

Here is my Logcat

```
09-06 20:51:33.237: E/AndroidRuntime(18192): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-06 20:51:33.237: E/AndroidRuntime(18192):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2893)
09-06 20:51:33.237: E/AndroidRuntime(18192):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3003)
09-06 20:51:33.237: E/AndroidRuntime(18192):    at com.bryanjrichardson.GSCC.BottlesActivity.call0(GoldandSilverCoinCalculatorActivity.java:857)
09-06 20:51:33.237: E/AndroidRuntime(18192):    at com.bryanjrichardson.GSCC.SimpleItemizedOverlay$1.onClick(SimpleItemizedOverlay.java:204)
09-06 20:51:33.237: E/AndroidRuntime(18192):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:174)
09-06 20:51:33.237: E/AndroidRuntime(18192):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-06 20:51:33.237: E/AndroidRuntime(18192):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-06 20:51:33.237: E/AndroidRuntime(18192):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3859)
09-06 20:51:33.237: E/AndroidRuntime(18192):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-06 20:51:33.237: E/AndroidRuntime(18192):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-06 20:51:33.237: E/AndroidRuntime(18192):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-06 20:51:33.237: E/AndroidRuntime(18192):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-06 20:51:33.237: E/AndroidRuntime(18192):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you sure you get the NPE from class 1? Can you paste your LogCat?

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah check my logcat.  startActivity(callIntent); is line 857

Comment: Can you include the Caused by part

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah there is no Caused by part.  that is all the logcat shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your 2 classes are **2 separated Activities**, your case will cause Null Pointer Exception, because when 2nd activity is running, 1st activity is stopped (terminated) -> this is Android OS mechanism, you can not change.

Solutions for your case:

- (1) Activity 1 is parent of others, this case is suitable for Application class or TabHost (complicated).
- (2) Create static method like **@Zapl's answer**; But it's still not quite nice because this static method should be in common use instead of inside Class 1 -> modify: Create a common Class like following:

This is utility class:

```
public class GlobalUtil
{
    public static void startUrlActivity(Context context, String url) {
    try {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        context.startActivity(callIntent); //<-- pass current activity or context
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
        Log.e("dialing-example", "Call failed", activityException);
        }
    }
}
```

And inside any other activity class you can call it:

```
GlobalUtil.startUrlActivity(this, "tel:1234567890"/*+phonenumber0*/");
```

OR

```
GlobalUtil.startUrlActivity(getBaseContext().getApplicationContext(), "your_url");
```

Comment: I'm not being allowed to use a static void.  When i remove the "static" in my second class it wants me to change the startUrlActivity from (Context, String) to (OnClickListener, String).

Comment: You review my answer: `context.startActivity(callIntent);` you have to call it from your current `context`. If you omit `context`, it means you call `this.startActivity(..)`

Comment: Do you create another class as `GlobalUtil` like I did? it will cost you no more code effort

Answer (score 0):

This will work if call0() is a method of the same activity class.

```
public void call0() {
    try {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:1234567890"));
        startActivity(callIntent); 
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
        Log.e("dialing-example", "Call failed", activityException);
    }
}
```

And dont forget to add this in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

And I dont think this a good thing:

```
BottlesActivity  inst = new BottlesActivity();
inst.call0();
```

Instead when the button is clicked, call call0() like below:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
     switch(v.getId()){
          case R.id.idButton:
                call0();
                break;

      }
}
```

Comment: Still no luck, its still throwing the null pointer on the same line as before.  I have my permissions in manifest.

Comment: Problem is you calling it from another activity. Why do you need call it this way?

Comment: I have a button in another class that has to use this function

Comment: Why not calling it the same activity. When the button is clicked, you call call0(); I dont see the need to call the method of another activity.

Comment: the button is in a public class that extends  another class that is a public abstract class that controls the function of my map overlay.  the button is within a @override protected boolean method

Comment: I am modifying this project here:  https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons/blob/master/android-mapviewballoons-example/src/mapviewballoons/example/simple/SimpleItemizedOverlay.java  in particular the ontapballoon method at the bottom.  I replaced the toast with a button to call method from another activity

Answer (score -1):

You can't create an `Activity` yourself. You could use a `static` method in another Activity class.

from any Activity:

```
BottlesActivity.call0(this);
```

in BottlesActivity

```
public static void call0(Context context) {
    try {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:1234567890"/*+phonenumber0*/));
        context.startActivity(callIntent); //<--This line causes nullpointerexception
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
        Log.e("dialing-example", "Call failed", activityException);
    }
}
```

Comment: startACtivity is not allowed within static method.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @zapl : You are correct that the OP shouldn't try to create an `Activity` directly but please do not advise exposing `public` methods (`static` or otherwise) in an `Activity`. This only leads to the misconception that `Activity` can be treated like any normal Java class which is not the case. The `Activity` class is a special case and should not expose `public` methods or data members to be used by other application components.

Comment: @B.Money `this.startActivity` (or just `startActivity`) is not because there is not `this` in a static context - but if you pass in a `Context` to act as `this` it is. @Squonk You are right, one should not abuse an `Activity` for such things although a `static` utility method is only minor abuse compared to trying to get access to members of active instances