# NullPointerException in ViewRootImpl when retunring from call (Only wit Samsung Touch)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have a very strange NullPointerException that 
(only occurs on Android 4.1, neither on ICS nor on Jelly Bean 4.2) **EDIT: Only on Samsung Touch devices.**

When pressing a button, I start an ACTION_CALL Activity from within one of mine like this:

```
final Uri dialInFormat = Uri.parse("tel:" + number + ",," + code + "#");
log.info("Starting call: " + dialInFormat);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, dialInFormat);
startActivity(intent);
```

The Phone Activity shows up and dials the number. But once I finish the call, come back to my application and touch the screen, following error occurs and the app is killed:

(Sometimes the error occurs earlier, while the phone is still dialing)

```
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354): Uncaught Exception
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawAccessibilityFocusedDrawableIfNeeded(ViewRootImpl.java:2431)
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.onHardwarePostDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2059)
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354):   at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1182)
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2275)
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2147)
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1958)
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1112)
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4518)
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
02-10 13:55:37.470: E/UCE(13354):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawAccessibilityFocusedDrawableIfNeeded(ViewRootImpl.java:2431)
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.onHardwarePostDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2059)
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1182)
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2275)
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2147)
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1958)
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1112)
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4518)
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
02-10 13:55:37.555: E/AndroidRuntime(13354):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any hint what could cause the NullPointer Exception? To busy main Thread? Incompatible UI elements? (I'm using the support Package, FragmentLayouts and the android.support.v4.view.ViewPager)

//Just ran into the same issue in a totally different context. I guess it has to do something with the ViewPager/PageAdapter

Comment: Refer to this quetion : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310453/how-do-i-resolve-nullpointerexception-when-calling-methods
also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12310504/1910290

and the\is answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12310684/1910290

Comment: These answers doesn't help at all. It's a complete different context.

Comment: this seems to be a error with the new accessability stuff, what do you get for AccessibilityManager.getInstance(context).isEnabled() and .isTouchExplorationEnabled() for the device where you get the nullpointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

We were using [Quick Actions Pop](http://www.androidpatterns.com/uap_pattern/quick-actions) for the menu where the phone call gets triggered. Before starting the call, I call dismiss on the PopupWindow.

```
public void dismiss() {
    AnimationSet shrinkAnimation = createAnimation(false);
    shrinkAnimation.setAnimationListener(mShrinkAnimationListener);

    mRoot.startAnimation(shrinkAnimation);
}
```

As you can see, an animation is triggered to dismiss the the Quick Action Pop. I guess Samsung Touch destroyed the Activity in the background, before the animation hand finished. Removing the anmiation and calling `super.dismiss()` instead solved the problem.

But again: This error only occurred on Samsung Touch devices.